# MySQL Invalid query: Too high level of nesting for select

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I switched the code to Andrews solution:

```
SELECT s1.biz_name, s1.biz_info, s1.e_address, s1.e_city, s1.e_state,
    s1.e_postal, s1.e_zip_full, s1.loc_LAT_centroid, s1.loc_LONG_centroid,
    s1.biz_phone, s1.biz_phone_ext, s1.biz_fax, s1.biz_email, s1.web_url,
    s2.upc as upc2, s2.retailprice as retailprice2, s2.dollar_sales as
    dollar_sales2, s2.dollar_sales_ly as dollar_sales_ly2, s2.todaydate as
    todaydate2, s2.datetimesql as datetimesql2, s2.shelfposition as
    shelfposition2, s2.reg_sale as reg_sale2, s2.representative as
    representative2, s2.notes as notes2, s3.upc as upc3, s3.retailprice as
    retailprice3, s3.dollar_sales as dollar_sales3, s3.dollar_sales_ly as
    dollar_sales_ly3, s3.todaydate as todaydate3, s3.datetimesql as
    datetimesql3, s3.shelfposition as shelfposition3, s3.reg_sale as reg_sale3,
    s3.representative as representative3, s3.notes as notes3, s4.upc as upc4,
    s4.retailprice as retailprice4, s4.dollar_sales as dollar_sales4,
    s4.dollar_sales_ly as dollar_sales_ly4, s4.todaydate as todaydate4,
    s4.datetimesql as datetimesql4, s4.shelfposition as shelfposition4,
    s4.reg_sale as reg_sale4, s4.representative as representative4, s4.notes as
    notes4, s5.upc as upc5, s5.retailprice as retailprice5, s5.dollar_sales as
    dollar_sales5, s5.dollar_sales_ly as dollar_sales_ly5, s5.todaydate as
    todaydate5, s5.datetimesql as datetimesql5, s5.shelfposition as
    shelfposition5, s5.reg_sale as reg_sale5, s5.representative as
    representative5, s5.notes as notes5 
FROM allStores AS s1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2
    ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address AND s2.upc = '650637119004' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s3 
    ON s1.e_address = s3.e_address AND s3.upc = '650637119011' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s4 
    ON s1.e_address = s4.e_address AND s4.upc = '650637374007' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s5 
    ON s1.e_address = s5.e_address AND s5.upc = '650637374014' 
WHERE  s2.e_address IS NOT NULL
    OR s3.e_address IS NOT NULL
    OR s4.e_address IS NOT NULL
    OR s5.e_address IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the new error: Invalid query: Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

Any other ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I feel like you shouldn't be joining on `storeCheckRecords` once per UPC.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but are you sure you need the sub queries? Can you just do JOINs to create your pivot table?

Comment: Your original problem is now lost to the sands of time. Also, is storeCheckRecords a view? DRapp's solution is looking better and better.

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to 
[MySQL bug #41156, List of derived tables acts like a chain of mutually-nested subqueries](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41156).

The bug log indicates it was verified against MySQL 5.0.72, 5.1.30, and 6.0.7.
Fixed in MySQL 5.1.37, MySQL 5.4.2 (which became 5.5.something), and NDB 7.1.0.

---

Regarding your redesigned query in the question above:

Pivot queries can be tricky.  You can use the method suggested by Andrew in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134539/20860).  If you search for many UPC values, you need to write application code to build the SQL query, appending as many JOIN clauses as the number of UPC values you're searching for.

MySQL does have a limit on the number of joins that can be done in a single query, but the example you should doesn't reach the limit.  That is, the query you show does work.

I assume that you're showing an example query searching for four UPC codes, whereas your app may construct the query dynamically for a greater number of UPC codes, and that may be more than 61 sometimes.

It looks like the goal of your query is to return stores that has at least one of the listed UPC codes.  You can do that more simply in the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
FROM allStores AS s
JOIN storeCheckRecords AS cr
  ON s.e_address = cr.e_address
     AND cr.upc IN ('650637119004','650637119011','650637374007','650637374014');
```

You can use this method in other ways, for example to find stores that have all four of the UPC's:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM allStores AS s
JOIN storeCheckRecords AS cr
  ON s.e_address = cr.e_address
     AND cr.upc IN ('650637119004','650637119011','650637374007','650637374014');
GROUP BY s.e_address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT upc) = 4;
```

Or to find stores that some but not all four of the UPC's:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM allStores AS s
JOIN storeCheckRecords AS cr
  ON s.e_address = cr.e_address
     AND cr.upc IN ('650637119004','650637119011','650637374007','650637374014');
GROUP BY s.e_address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT upc) < 4;
```

Or to find stores that lack all four of the UPC's:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM allStores AS s
JOIN storeCheckRecords AS cr
  ON s.e_address = cr.e_address
     AND cr.upc IN ('650637119004','650637119011','650637374007','650637374014');
WHERE cr.e_address IS NULL;
```

You still have to write some code to build this query, but it's a bit easier to do, and it doesn't exceed any limits on the number of joins or subqueries you can run.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the same results without using subqueries:

```
SELECT s1.biz_name,
       ...
       s2.upc             AS upc2,
       ...
       s3.upc             AS upc3,
       ...
       s4.upc             AS upc4,
       ...
       s5.upc             AS upc5,
       ...
FROM allStores AS s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2 ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s3 ON s1.e_address = s3.e_address
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s4 ON s1.e_address = s4.e_address
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s5 ON s1.e_address = s5.e_address
WHERE  (s2.e_address IS NOT NULL
OR s3.e_address IS NOT NULL
OR s4.e_address IS NOT NULL
OR s5.e_address IS NOT NULL)  
AND (s2.upc = '650637119004' OR s2.upc IS NULL)
AND (s3.upc = '650637119011' OR s3.upc IS NULL)
AND (s4.upc = '650637374007' OR s4.upc IS NULL)
AND (s5.upc = '650637374014' OR s5.upc IS NULL)
```

Comment: Actually, this would only return a record if all 4 joins were successful since your "WHERE" clause has an explicit "AND".  If you moved your "AND s?.upc = '...'" elements to the LEFT OUTER JOIN portion it WOULD work.  The where clause IMPLIES a must be found.

Comment: @DRapp you are correct! I try to keep things that aren't joining the tables out of the ON clause for the sake of clarity. Fixing my ans...

Comment: I switched to your solution and posted the new error.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify to just get all the elements first with a simple WHERE IN clause...  You appear to be doing a pivot table to show T1 to T2 to T3 to T4 to T5.  If you get all the data in individual rows, then you can have STATIC columns across the top showing the details per row under each other.

```
SELECT 
      t1.brand,
      t1.biz_name,
      t1.biz_info,
      t1.e_address,
      t1.e_city,
      t1.e_state,
      t1.e_postal,
      t1.e_zip_full,
      t1.loc_LAT_centroid,
      t1.loc_LONG_centroid,
      t1.biz_phone,
      t1.biz_phone_ext,
      t1.biz_fax,
      t1.biz_email,
      t1.web_url,
      t1.upc,
      t1.retailprice,
      t1.dollar_sales,
      t1.dollar_sales_ly,
      t1.todaydate,
      t1.datetimesql,
      t1.shelfposition,
      t1.reg_sale,
      t1.representative,
      t1.notes 
   FROM 
      storeCheckRecords as t1 
   WHERE 
      t1.upc IN ( '650637119004', '650637119011', '650637374007', '650637374014')
```

such as..

```
Brand  Bus Addr                  UPC        Retail$     Sales        Notes
xyz    Bus Name                  UPC        ... etc...  Cur Yr 
       Bus Info                  Shelf Info             Last Yr
       Address, (Cit/State/Zip)
       Lat / Long
       Phone / Fax
       Email / Web

----
Next Entry
```

Does it really matter that exact same address is the same as opposed to who carries an item?  What if one entry is "123 Main St", another is "123B Main St", and "123 Main St - Suite B", you wouldn't find a match.

Additionally, you mention some having up to 75 UPC codes...  Put those in a separate table and use that as the first table joined to the "StoreCheckRecords" and get them all... instead of manually keying all the columns suffixed from 2 to 75... or however many on the next run being only 17, and yet another 4...  I think you may be too fixed into what you are trying to get out from the data.

You could even GROUP by the common "e_address" you originally wanted the matches based on and provide that group as a break between sections reported to the user.

Comment: Thank you but I am returning the results to a google map and need all the details per store. Therefore I would need upc1,upc2,upc3... etc.  Can that be done with this query?

Comment: @user1184169, although I've not worked with Google maps, I would be very surprised why they would do a NON data-normalization approach to generating data.  Is there some spec you are working against by Google I could look at.