# Mysql ORDER by date, but filter results

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 4 tables `A,B,C,D` with records and `datetime` field in each table.

Currently Im using `UNION ALL` and `ORDER BY Date DESC`.

The problem is if a table `A` has 10 records added today, and table `B` has 10 records added yesterday then the first 10 results are all from table `A`.

Is it possible to get records ordered by date, but mix them between all 4 tables?

First record will be the latest added from table `A`, then the latest added from table `B`, then `C`, then `D`. And cycle them like that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a ranking function - but you can simulate it with variables. I suggest trying something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 'A' as tbl 
 from (SELECT * FROM (SELECT  A.* FROM A ORDER BY `date` desc) sa) a, 
      (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
 union all
 select *, @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank, 'B' as tbl 
 from (select * from (SELECT  B.* FROM B ORDER BY `date` desc) sb) b, 
      (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r2
 union all
 select *, @rownum3 := @rownum3 + 1 AS rank, 'C' as tbl 
 from (select * from (SELECT  C.* FROM C ORDER BY `date` desc) sc) c, 
      (SELECT @rownum3 := 0) r3
 union all
 select *, @rownum4 := @rownum4 + 1 AS rank, 'D' as tbl 
 from (select * from (SELECT  D.* FROM D ORDER BY `date` desc) sd) d, 
      (SELECT @rownum4 := 0) r4
) s
order by rank, tbl
```

Alternatively, try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT S.*, 
        @rownum := CASE WHEN @tblvar <> S.tbl THEN 0 ELSE @rownum+1 END AS rank, 
        @tblvar := S.tbl AS tblvar 
 FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT  A.*, 'A' as tbl FROM A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  B.*, 'B' as tbl FROM B
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  C.*, 'C' as tbl FROM C
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  D.*, 'D' as tbl FROM D) U
  ORDER BY tbl, `date` desc) S,
 (SELECT @rownum := 0) R,
 (SELECT @tblvar := '!') T
) Q
order by rank, tbl
```

Comment: what does num stands for? it gives me error like no such a field

Comment: ok, I tried this, changed num to *. Honestly, I dont know what all this does, so many subqueries, but apparently this is working and not that slow. you are genius, thanks!

Comment: daaaaaaamn, on my local machine it works fine, but on the live server it throws: mysqld-5.0.67-community-nt-log]Too high level of nesting for select. oh, well.

Comment: @galgai: I have corrected `num` to be `*` - that was something I should have fixed when I was trying out a variant of the query. Are the "tables" A, B, C and D actually tables, or are they views or derived tables on the server? If it's the latter, this behaviour is a known bug, documented here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41156 . (Found via Bill Karwin's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134320 )

Comment: they are actual tables. It says there: 
Suggested fix:
sql_yacc.yy: add "Lex->nest_level--;" at the end of "select_derived" or "'(' get_select_lex select_derived union_opt ')' opt_table_alias" rule. Is this file sql_yacc.yy in mysql folder? I couldnt find it.

Comment: @galgai: The suggested fix in the bug report refers to how the MySQL *source code* could be fixed - sql_yacc.yy is a MySQL source code file; it's not a fix you can implement to your existing installation. It seems odd that you are experiencing this problem with actual tables; it's only supposed to occur with 63 levels of nesting, which you certainly shouldn't be getting with the above query.

Comment: Ive got 12 tables, but it works on my local machine with mysql 5.1. If I remove the 12th query, it works on live server, but with 12th query it doesnt.

Comment: @galgai: It still sounds to me as though some of the "tables" on the live server are actually views / derived tables, even if all of the tables on your local machine are actual tables. I have added an alternative (untested) version of the query to my answer, which I think should have fewer levels of nesting - can you try it?

Comment: works great! Thanks a lot Mark, I was gonna upgrade mysql, but now its not needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but I think you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  datediff((select max(`date`) from A), `date`) as d_diff,
  1 as tab
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT
  B.*,
  datediff((select max(`date`) from B), `date`) as d_diff,
  2 as tab
FROM B
ORDER BY d_diff, tab, `date` desc
```

or maybe this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  A.* FROM A ORDER BY `date` desc limit 5) a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  B.* FROM B ORDER BY `date` desc limit 5) b
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

based on your comments, this should work, but could also be slow:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  (select count(*) from A A1 where A1.dat>A.dat) as i,
  1 as tab
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT
  B.*,
  (select count(*) from B B1 where B1.dat>B.dat) as i,
  2 as tab
FROM B
order by i, tab
```

(can be made faster using variables, but I like plain SQL more)

Comment: tried it now, it does almost the same thing as just order by date - pulling 10 records straight just from one table.

Comment: @galgai both queries return records mixed from all tables, i'll edit my first one to make it cycle like you want... let me know, but i think it should be okay....

Comment: @galgai dates have gaps? maybe that's the problem... but i am thinking about it....

Comment: fthiella, if it gives you any hint, all tables have field that identifies them - table A has field with its table name, B.C.D the same. I tried group by tablename field, but it pulls only 4 records (one from each table) as there are only 4 tables, thats it perfect , but how to cycle it I dont know.

Comment: tried above solution on just 2 tables, and it took 2 minutes to execute! But still the first 10 records are from one table...